# Approximately equivalent symbol?

Tags: symbols

I want to write a "*approximately equivalent*" symbol, which has three strokes like equivalent symbol `$$\equiv$$` (≡), but the strokes are like that of approximate symbol `$$\approx$$` (≈)

Do you know how to write it in LaTeX?

Comment: This seems to be U+224b ≋ and `\approxident` in `unicode-math` or `stix` packages.

Comment: You may also want to have a look to [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/13304)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I use stacks to set 3 `\sim`s vertically.  The `scalerel` package allows me to preserve the math style of the invocation, and to define the stacking gap as a combination of `.5pt` plus 1.5 scaled-to-local-math-style points, given as `1.5\LMpt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\def\apeqA{\SavedStyle\sim}
\def\apeq{\setstackgap{L}{\dimexpr.5pt+1.5\LMpt}\ensurestackMath{%
  \ThisStyle{\mathrel{\Centerstack{{\apeqA} {\apeqA} {\apeqA}}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \apeq B \equiv C$\par
$\scriptstyle A \apeq B \equiv C$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A \apeq B \equiv C$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you can use the `stix` package (or `unicode-math`), then the symbol is available as `\approxident`.

Note however that `\usepackage{stix}` in a pdfLaTeX document will change *all* math symbols. Also importing only the symbol from the STIX fonts might give one that's not compatible with your symbols.

There is a solution in the Comprehensive List of Symbols:

```
\newcommand*{\approxident}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
  \hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}}
```

If you don't need the symbol in subscripts, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

If the symbol `\approxident` is not available, see greg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238485/16967),
the following definition provides the symbol by using `\sim` three times moved with a gap close to the gap of the `\equiv` symbol (more or less because of line thickness issues).

The symbol works in the different math style versions and the lower border of the bounding box is fixed to get a correct bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\approxident}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@approxident\sim
  }%
}   
\newcommand*{\@approxident}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: \sim
  % Math axis in \ht0
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  % Gap stored in \dimen2, approximated by the half height
  % of \equiv, which is centered around the math axis.
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\equiv$}%
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\ht2 - \ht0\relax
  % The wave symbol of #2 (\sim) is stored in box 4
  \sbox4{$\m@th#1\sim$}%
  % and the half height is calculated in \dimen4
  \dimen4=\dimexpr\ht4 - \ht0\relax
  % Then the movement for the gap in the following \vcenter
  % is calculated in \dimen6
  \dimen0=\dimexpr
    % go back
    -\ht4 - \dp4 %
    % add gap
    + \dimen2 %
  \relax
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \copy4 %
    \kern\dimen0 %
    \copy4 %
    \kern\dimen0 %
    \copy4 %
    % Correction for the lower bounding box border, if the
    % wave symbol does not extend to the base line
    \ifdim\dp4=\z@
      \kern\dimexpr -\ht0 + \dimen4\relax
    \fi
  }%   
}      
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
    \fbox{$\approxident$}\;
    \equiv\approxident\;   
    \scriptstyle\equiv\approxident\;
    \scriptscriptstyle\equiv\approxident
  \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]